# I did not know if I "will be able to" or "would be able to"?

Tags: past-tense

> I did not know if I *will be able to* or *would be able to*?

I'm a bit confused about the difference and I don't know which keyword to look for!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/is-would-the-past-future-tense-of-will-or-just-a-modal-verb check this one

Comment: Using ***would*** may (but doesn't *have* to) imply that the speaker is talking about not being able to do something *in some hypothetical situation, which might not **actually** arise*.

Comment: There's not enough context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "would" the past future tense of "will" or just a modal verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/is-would-the-past-future-tense-of-will-or-just-a-modal-verb)

Comment: If you say *I will be able to*, people will think you are promising to do it. If you say *I would be able to*, people will probably think you are promising to do it, but only ***if*** somebody asks you to.

Answer (score 2):

Saying "I will be able to help you," implies that you will help the person you are speaking to, and there is no obstacle in the way of you doing so.

Saying "I would be able to help you," implies that you theoretically could help the person out, but there may be something that prevents you from doing so at some point.

In conversation, most people pay no attention to that difference and use "will" and "would" interchangeably. If the speaker follows up with a statement such as, "but I have no free time next week," then you know that they really can't help you. Otherwise, I think it's all up to the context and your interpretation of the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you speak about your knowledge in the *past* (using **did**), **will** (from *I don't know if I will*) transforms into **would** to make tenses agree. That combination of tenses is called *Future in the Past*:

https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html

I **did**n't (did not) know if I **would** be able to.